# Global command to destroy all disconnected data files in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, sqlplus, oracle-sql-developer

Is there a global command to delete/purge all disconnected `.bdf` files in an Oracle 11g R2 database?

Here is the scenario:

Every user-defined user and user-defined tablespace was deleted from an Oracle 11g R2 database by successfully executing the following commands for each and every user-defined user and tablespace:

```
DROP USER username CASCADE;
DROP TABLESPACE tablespacename INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
```

However, the folder containing the `.dbf` files corresponding with all the dropped tablespaces still contains all the same `.dbf` files, each with the same original file size.  It is thus as if the data has simply been detached from the database without destroying the underlying datafiles.

I hesitate to simply delete all of the corresponding `.dbf` files out of fear of side-effects.  So **is there a global command in Oracle 11g R2 that will enable an administrator to safely delete all unused data files that were once connected with the Oracle 11g R2 instance?**

I am using SQL Developer and SQLPlus, so any command or utility either of these tools could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description of this behaviour and your other comment, I guess your database runs on Windows.

The command you used should suffice and delete the datafiles. Except on Windows. On Windows, the datafiles are not always deleted, it is a known limitation.

Before dropping tablespaces or datafiles, take them offline:

`alter tablespace ... offline;`

or

`alter database datafile ... offline drop;`

And drop the datafile/tablespace after the above:

`drop tablespace ... including contents and datafiles;`

or

`alter tablespace ... drop datafile ...;`

If they still remain there, just simply delete them at OS level. And no, there is no such command thats deletes datafiles from the database that the database does not know of.

Reference:

[Drop Tablespace Including Contents And Datafiles The Datafiles Are Not Automatically Deleted (Doc ID 389467.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=389467.1)

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to look into this.  I have deleted the files as you suggested, given that the commands in the OP have already been run and failed to delete them.  The `.dbf` files are thus now in the Windows recycle bin.  Are there any other precautions that I should take to clean up Oracle 11g before trying to import more schema and data using other scripts?  Also, is it safe to empty the windows recycle bin and thus permanently eliminate these `.dbf` files?  I plan another data pump to replace all this from scratch, and want things clean first to avoid errors.

Comment: I do not have an oracle support account, so I cannot read your link.  But thank you for what you posted in your answer as best practices for avoiding similar problems in the future.

Comment: @HereAndThere Yes, you can empty the recycle bin. I don't know what you plan to import, but some object types, like views, stored procedures, packages are not stored in user tablespaces, hence they are not dropped (they are stored in the dictionary, in the SYSTEM tablespace). If I were to re-import an existing schema, I would drop the schema first.

Comment: Thank you.  How do I drop the schema?  I imagine the steps are 1.) query all schemas, 2.) identify the ones to delete, then 3.) delete schemas by name.  But how do I do that in Oracle 11g?  What commands?  If you think this is a separate question, I need help framing it so that I do not spam the ssite with poorly defined questions.

Comment: Once you successfully issue a DROP TABLESPACE, any remaining file(s) from that tablespace has no more meaning to oracle than does a Word document.  There are no leftover connections to the database.  So nothing you do to it either directly or from the recycle bin has any meaning at all to oracle.

Comment: As for your second question - 'how do I drop a schema' - exactly like you showed in your first msg. DROP USER .. CASCADE. Note that a user may have objects in more than one TS, and a given TS may have objects from more than one schema.  There is no inherent one-to-one relationship between users (schemas) and tablespaces.

Comment: @EdStevens Thank you.  So then would I be completely cleaning out the schemas and tablespaces if I use the following three commands in the following sequence: `.) `drop user ... cascade;`, 2.) `alter tablespace ... offline;`, and 3.) `drop tablespace ... including contents and datafiles;`?  Would these three commands also clean the dictionary in the SYSTEM tablespace as BalazsPapp suggested?

Comment: I am trying to do a data pump import to test how effective this delete exercise was.  But I am encountering an obstacle that I documented in a separate posting.  Are you willing to take a look?  Here is the link: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130732/how-do-i-open-data-pump-import-wizard-in-sql-developer-4-1

Comment: Yes, those commands should work.  Just be aware of what I said about tablespaces being able to contain segments from more than one user.  Just because you drop a user, that does not mean that a given tablespace is now empty. It could very well still have segments belonging to other users.  Query dba_segments to see.  You misunderstand what @BalzasPapp said.  If you drop a user, **everything** belonging to that user is gone, including objects that are in the SYSTEM ts.