# How do I open Data Pump Import Wizard in SQL Developer 4.1?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, oracle-sql-developer

How do I find and open the Data Pump Import Wizard in SQL Developer 4.1?

I opened the Help search tool in SQL Developer 4.1 and searched for Data Pump, and found directions that include:

1.) Select `View > DBA` from the View menu.
2.) Expand a connection in DBA Navigator.
3.) Right click on `Import Jobs.`
4.) Select `Data Pump Import Wizard`.

The problem is that, when I expand a connection in what seems to be DBA Navigator (after selecting `View > DBA`), there is no `Import Jobs` option, even though there are many other options listed.  I did go to the trouble of expanding every single option including nested submenus, and there still was no `Import Jobs` option anywhere.

In addition to the embedded help within SQL Developer 4.1, I also googled for instructions, but the results were only for version 3.1, [such as this link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-developer-31-data-pump-wizards).

I am trying to import data into an Oracle 11g r2 database using the Data Pump Import Wizard.

**So how do I open the `Data Pump Import Wizard` in SQL Developer 4.1?**

Comment: here is doc [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/intro.htm#RPTUG45283)

Comment: @JSapkota Thank you.  The link says to right click the Data Pump Import Wizard option, but it does not say what to right click on to get that option, and I cannot seem to find that option no matter where I click within a connection's sub-options.

Comment: @JSapkota THANK YOU for talking with me about this.  Your interaction helped me find the answer myself.  I was digging into the `Connections Navigator`.  I did not realize that the `DBA Navigator` required me to add a connection from those listed in the `Connections Navigator` before I could see the options like `Data Pump`.  This question is now answered.

Answer (score 1):

View > DBA

[image]

Add a Connection

Expand the tree.

Go to the Data Pump node.

Expand, expand again to get to existing DP Import Jobs.

This will show the results of

```
SELECT
    name,
    fname,
    type
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            job_name name,
            owner_name
            || '.'
            || job_name fname,
            'DATAPUMP_IMPORT_JOBS' type
        FROM
            dba_datapump_jobs
        WHERE
            TRIM(operation) = 'IMPORT'
    )
```

To create a new one, right-click and use the Wizard.

[image]